# Input width bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form using bootstrap, but when I load the page the input field width takes all the page, like this:

[image]

My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="adicionaProduto" method="post">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control"/><br><br>
        <label for="nome">Valor</label>
        <input type="text" name="valor" class="form-control"/><br><br>
        <label for="nome">Quantidade</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantidade" class="form-control"/><br><br>
        <label for="nome">Código</label>
        <input type="text" name="cod" class="form-control"/><br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Novo</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I would like that the field was smaller than this. I tried the width="" in the input tag, but didn't work.

I have no experience in front end. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add styling direct to the input field

for example

```
<input type="text" style="width:250px;" name="nome" class="form-control"/>
```

Also

```
<input type="text" style="max-width:250px;" name="nome" class="form-control"/>
```

You can also put it on a div with regulated width

e.g.

```
<div style="max-width:250px">
<input type="text"  name="nome" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your bootstrap template has specified css for those input-tags. You can inspect your webpage to see what css is applied on the elements and you can replace the css you want by putting something like this in your .css-file:

```
input{
width: 50%!important;
}
```

The keyword "!important" will make your css go first.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap scaffolding. Put it in

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"> your form></div>
</div>
```

Ah and using col-md-xxx you can adjust size. Please see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic